# How to access local downloaded videos(files) of the filesystem in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-device-explorer

I'am use Android Studio 4.0 on Mac(Linux/Mac system).
I want to copy downloaded videos to my computer  from android emulator.

So I want to install android app from Play Store.
Inside app, downloaded and watched videos.

By the way I'm not sure this videos is saving on sdCard, caching or whatever. But I could not access this files.

I tried 2 different ways that listed below to find videos.

1-) Look at the **~/.android/avd/** for unix/mac system.

> By default, the android tool creates the AVD directory inside
> ~/.android/avd/
> [image]

2-) Android Studio, View -> Tools -> Device File Explorer.
Opened left panel, but not have videos inside those files.
[image]

Do you have any suggestions with this issue?

I can not try real device, because I am using iPhone currently.

Comment: `So I want to install android app from Play Store.(Paid apps) Inside app, downloaded and watched videos.` this doesn't sound legal/fair ? are you trying to get the videos from other apps ?

Comment: Actually, Yes, Because this videos normally public/accessible videos the other countries via web page. But I can not access normal way. So, this fair and legal not thieves. On the other hand, apple and google banned if you thieves or do not have legal rights. I'am at least as sensitive as you. Thank you by the way :)

Comment: well, it's worth asking, because if the developers wanted you to have access to the videos, then it would have been simple to get them. if i made an app with videos, i wouldn't want others to gain access to them and distribute it freely, that's why i'm asking

Comment: You are right. But in app, videos is not important. Because you can extra work on videos to get same result. For example, you create an video clip app that  can cut videos frames, can paste videos and also add sound to video.  I wan to sound clip that accessible anywhere in the other counrty but not from here. is it ok for you :) if you are convinced, maybe you can show me right way.

Comment: `opened left panel, but not have videos inside this files. ` You will not see them in that picture. But did you browse the directories /sdcard and /storage for them? /sdcard/Download  ?

Comment: Of course I looked there.  As you can see, all files size nearly 3 KB(You can see last column in picture which I added above). According to my opinion, videos size should bigger than those sizes .

Comment: try sdcard/android/data/<app.package.name>

Comment: Already checked there, files is empty. Also you can see sdcard total size 21 B(You can see last column in picture which I added above). This size looks quite small for the size of the video. @kelvin

Comment: @EmreGürses but your sdcard wont have just 21 B right? can you tell the application name? if your device is on android 11 the downloaded videos should be in downloads or in app specific storage. from android 11 they wont be able to save the files on Sdcard in some random folder

Comment: Emulator is Pixel 3a, Android 9. Can I try other emulator with android 11? If yes, please suggest which one :)